# Simplify scritps in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, handbrake

This is my first post, so apologie in advance.
I normally use HandBrake to encode to 265 all my files, but the problem is not passthrough for subs, those change to ssa (from srt). This format is a problem for my TV, TVbox, etc... I prefer the subs like tracks, not burn it, for use them when need it... Reading and reading, finally find a script to encode to 265, but is much easier for me use a GUI, mostly if I have to change something (totally noob)
So, when I encode to 265 with HB, I convert ssa to srt with this script:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -metadata title="" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -c:s srt "/out path/${i%.*}.mkv"
```

And work nice, but the problem is a font size. I don't know why change from 24 to 75 or 105.
Then I extract srt from original mkv with this:

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:s:0 "${f%.mkv}01.srt" -map 0:s:1 "${f%.mkv}02.srt";
```

Also works, but delete metadata and language, and I am still looking for do this wright.
I tryed like this

```
fmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:0 -metadata:s:s:0 language:spa "${f%.mkv}01.srt" -map 1 -metadata:s:s:1 language:spa "${f%.mkv}02.srt"
```

but don't work.
Also I try to add subs into mkv again, but either work:

```
    for filename in *.mkv; 
  if [ -f "${filename01}" ]; [ -f "${filename02}" ]; then
ffmpeg -i "$filename" -f srt -i "$filename01" -f srt -i "$filename02" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt "/out/${i%.*}.mkv"
  fi
done
```

Any chance to make it easer?
The script I probe for encode is:

```
 for filename in *.mkv
    do 
      ffmpeg -i "$filename" -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -x265-params profile=main10 -map 0:0 -c:a copy -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c:s copy -map 0:3 -map 0:4 "/out path/${i%.*}.mkv"
done
```

But is not the same result of HB. Maybe the scale or crop and also, select specific audio/video quality/size.

Sorry for all this. I really have a mass with ffmpeg.
Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

So, trying, searching, reading... finally find something.
I still using HB to encode, and after that, still change format of subtitle, but, in the script, just change srt for text.
Now subtitles are with normal font size and can see in every device.

New script to change ssa subs to srt with normal font size:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -metadata title="" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -c:s text "/out path/${i%.*}.mkv"
```

Grettings!!